# How to conduct an A/B test on time series

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, ab-test

Assuming I have time series for different for some consumers visiting a website.
The time series would look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,1,1,1,
                               2,2,2,2,
                               3,3,3,3,
                               4,4,4,4], 
                    'time': [1,2,3,4,
                             1,2,3,4,
                             1,2,3,4,
                             1,2,3,4], 
                    'clicked': [0,0,0,1,
                                0,1,0,1,
                                0,0,0,0,
                                1,1,1,1],
                   'group': ['control','control','control','control',
                            'control','control','control','control',
                            'treatment','treatment','treatment','treatment',
                            'treatment','treatment','treatment','treatment']})
foo

user_id time    clicked group
0   1   1   0   control
1   1   2   0   control
2   1   3   0   control
3   1   4   1   control
4   2   1   0   control
5   2   2   1   control
6   2   3   0   control
7   2   4   1   control
8   3   1   0   treatment
9   3   2   0   treatment
10  3   3   0   treatment
11  3   4   0   treatment
12  4   1   1   treatment
13  4   2   1   treatment
14  4   3   1   treatment
15  4   4   1   treatment
```

which indicate if a `user_id`, `clicked` on a banner at a specific `time`.
Lets assume that at `time >=3` I changed the position of the banner, **but only** for the `treatment group`.

What should I run an A/B test in order to see the the change of the banner was successful ?

Should the A/B test be:

- **within** the `treatment group`, `time <=2` vs `time >=3` ?
- or check the difference on `click` for the `treatment group` before and after the change of the position of the banner, **and then** compare this difference with the difference on `click` for the `control group` before and after the change of the position of the banner ? If so, how can I compare 2 differences in a statistical way ?
- or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

If the users are randomized to control/treatment, then the pre-period doesn't really matter.  This is because the difference in whatever metric you're measuring is 0 in expectation since the users come from the same population.  You could use it to gain efficiency for the treatment effect, but it isn't neccesary.

Depending on what your hypothesis is, you could simply compare:

- Number of users who click at least once, or
- Number of clicks

Between groups in the post period.  Alternatively, you could perform a regression using the pre-period behaviour as a predictor.

Comment: If I compare the pre and post within the treatment group, is it the same with comparing the treatment and control group for the post period ? I mean, conclusion-wise (e.g. if moving the banner was successful or not). Considering that the sampling for the control and treatment group was done correctly

Comment: No, it isn't the same.  The cleanest comparison is control v treatment, during the period in which the intervention was made.

Comment: How would you interpret statistical difference between pre and post within the treatment group, and at the same time no statistical difference between control and treatment in post ?

Comment: @quant You're free to search "change from baseline" here or elsewhere to answer that question.

Comment: @quant But for example, this could just be regression to the mean.  One group has an unusually large click rate, which decreases due to regression to the mean.